# T_STRING error - Trying to use PHP array in SQL where statement

Tags: php, mysql

I feel like I'm making a rookie error here somewhere but can't figure out what's going wrong.  I am using PHP and mySQL.  I have an array $users that stores a current user's information.  The array is storing the customer id (cid, its an integer).  So I'm trying to pull information that is only tagged to a specific customer.  My code is:

```
try
{
    $sql = 'SELECT id, title, image_url FROM shelf WHERE cid = $user['cid']'; 
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
```

I feel like I have similar code in other parts of my program that are working so this seems like I may be doing something wrong in terms of syntax.  If I replace `$user['cid']` in the request with a hard-coded number like 22, the statement works fine.  However, I need to pull the integer from $user.  I'm getting a `T_STRING` error on the SELECT statement line. I have also tried to add an additional set of single quotes around `$user['cid']` but that's not working either (i.e. `$user['cid']`)

Thanks for your help.

Twine

Comment: Try using double quotes instead of single quotes to assign your string

Comment: Why are you using an editor without syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using PDO, so you should be using place-holders, too:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, title, image_url FROM shelf WHERE cid=:cid');
$stmt->bindParam(':cid', $user['cid']);
$stmt->execute();
```

This ensures your data is escaped correctly and handles conversion to the appropriate database format where required.

Comment: Needle in a haystack some days, I swear. Thanks for the props.

Comment: Tadman, you nailed it.  I had previously tried using placeholders and it still wasn't working.  I had added in a $result = $r->fetch(); afterwards.  I excluded it based on your advice and its working now.

Comment: @OrangeTwine if his answer solved your problem, make sure you click on the check mark to accept this as an answer.

Comment: Stick with placeholders. They'll serve you well.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, rookie error. Change to double quotes and add { } around value like:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, image_url FROM shelf WHERE cid = {$user['cid']}";
```

Comment: How do you know if it's not escaped earlier?

Comment: If it's not *obvious* it's escaped, you cannot *presume* it's escaped.

Comment: The query string is _obviously_ not a place to escape query value. Good luck applying set of filters while concating a string.

Comment: The query string is the **ONLY** place to escape a value. Period. This is not up for debate. If you're using string interpolation to insert values in your queries in PDO you are doing it wrong.

Comment: If it's the only place, so how come your example escapes it somewhere else? The escape is done by bindParam method, not in the query string. But I wont argue about details and I admit, in case of PDO your example is the right way to go, but the question was how to get rid of T_STRING error.

Comment: To be pedantic, yes, the escaping is performed after the fact when the query is executed, but the declaration of where it should be escaped is using a placeholder. It is blindingly obvious where the escaping is done if you use those, and often left as a mystery if you don't. Values such as `:cid` and `?` can be considered safely escaped where `{$user['cid']}` cannot be reasonably presumed to be as such.

Answer (score -2):

$sql = 'SELECT id, title, image_url FROM shelf WHERE cid = '.intval($user['cid']);

Comment: I'd slightly prefer `(int) $user['cid']` over `intval`

Comment: Author says "However, I need to pull the integer from $user". I give the way how to do it and get -1. Very nice. Thanks.

Comment: `intval` is not a substitute for [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). If you do this on a regular basis you're creating a whole world of hurt for yourself.

Comment: What's wrong with using `(int)` or `intval` for protecting integers in queries?

Comment: If you mean the way it's written, I agree. I prefer using placeholders. But in current context what I wrote seems to be a nice way to fix the bug and find out what's going on + prevent injection of course.

Please tell if intval or (int) work wrong, it would be very interesting for me at least.

Comment: They're not a general purpose solution to escaping and lead to a false sense of security. You shouldn't have several obscure ways for escaping values when there's a facility in PDO that handles all of them with a very simple placeholder system.